# import/export big files, avoiding memory exhausted errors

Tags: php, symfony, memory, import, background-process

In my application I have an import function which allows the user to import data from a csv file into my application as well as export the existing data).

The problem is that the imported files might have many records and in the import method I am creating lots of related objects, so in certain circustances it cause memory exhausted error.

I am looking for ways to optimize my code. I am already using $em->clear and gc_collect_cycles functions and I know about Doctrine2 batch methods. 
Would be possible to create a background process just for import the file (running a console command for example?

What are the best practices for this kind of situations?. 
I know for example OroCrm Project uses commands for their installer, while displaying a loader to the users and their installations runs very smoothly.

Looking foward for your opiniions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course run a console command.  But Doctrine 2 is not ideal for batch operations and will soon run out of gas.

I have a process using PDO which routinely scans a csv file with 110K records and updates as many as five different tables.  It runs fine even on my $5 per month shared host server.

Make a PDO service:

```
# =============================================================
pdo:
    class: PDO
    arguments:
        dsn:      '%database_dsn%'      # mysql:dbname=appgames
        user:     '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
    calls:
        - [setAttribute, [ 3, 2]] # \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,           \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        - [setAttribute, [19, 2]] # \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        - [setAttribute, [20, 0]] # \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES
```

Prepare some statements:

```
public function prepareLevelInsert()
{
    $key = 'levelInsert';

    if (isset($this->prepared[$key])) return $this->prepared[$key];

    $sql = <<<EOT
INSERT INTO levels
       ( id,  name, sport, domain, domainSub, status)
VALUES (:key,:name,:sport,:domain,:domainSub, 'Active')
;
EOT;
    return $this->prepared[$key] = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
}
```

Then scan through your file

```
// $conn is the PDO object or a 
// DBAL connection object obtained from $entityManager->getConnection();
$conn->beginTransaction();
while($row = fgetcsv($fp))
{
    // Pull level data
    $level = array('name' => $row['levelName'] ... rest of values ...);

    // And insert
    $this->prepareLevelInsert()->execute($level);
}
$conn->commit();
```

A bit tedious perhaps but magnitudes faster than using Doctrine 2.